# Listing core windows processes and services

Tags: c#, process

I'm in a bit of a pinch here and I'd like to get a list of processes running on a machine that associate with windows itself, or are required to be running all the time like a background process or antivirus.

I'm making this program to keep my skills up to scratch, so it will likely never be released on a large scale.

Basically, I'm making an app that scans the computer for programs and only allows those on the whitelist to run. I need to automatically have all windows processes, and those in the startup folder added to this list.

Programs that are not on the list are terminated after a 30 second warning.

I've already gone through several posts on stack, and a google search yielded minimal results.

Is there a way I can differentiate process as a windows process by scanning some metadata or getting the original file path of that process and scanning the file?

PS:
Is there a way to scan all installed programs like in control panel and list them?

Comment: "Is there a way to scan all installed programs like in control panel and list them?" -- Control Panel's "Programs and Features" just lists the info found in the registry under SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, as far as I know.

Comment: So as long as a user can get software to install itself or register itself for startup, it's fine? Are you trying to prevent having to set up group policies or install a virus scanner? What if a Windows update installs an essential program that's not on your whitelist, are you going to kill Windows? In other words, this sounds like an XY problem, please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want to do this for security reasons then don't write your own tool. It's much better to rely on existing solutions such as AppLocker.

Comment: Hrm... Yes this is tricky and will require updates based on the windows environment. I'm making an app to restrict certain apps from running within a timeframe, example to prevent children from playing games whilst allowing homework programs like office and internet explorer to run. If there was a way I could list all active process and scan the original file for a certificate with microsoft's name on it, that would add it to the list. @Scott Chamberlain. I'd like to write my own for fun mostly, and to keep my c# skills up to peak whilst on study break.

Comment: @CausticLasagne Actually I am just going to delete my old comments. Please edit your question to include the fact you are doing this more to practice than to actually stop anyone. you can delete your old comments now if you want.

Comment: The "appwiz" I also covered here: http://superuser.com/questions/649083/what-is-the-rationale-behind-using-a-third-party-uninstaller-when-uninstalling/649094#649094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I did it. Finally.

Thanks to all that helped.

I ended up taking a snapshot of all running processes at the time before the timer is enabled and new processes not on the list are blocked. Processes that cannot be closed are likely viruses, or system components. I've never seen an app or a game block process killing before, and parents must ensure task manager is closed before running the timer.

CausticLasagne.